# Most pythonic way to concatenate pandas cells with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame, with city and arr columns:

```
city      arr  final_target
paris     11   paris_11
paris     12   paris_12
dallas    22   dallas
miami     15   miami
paris     16   paris_16
```

My goal is to fill the final_target column concatenating paris and arr number, when city name is Paris, and just filling with the name when the name is not Paris.

What is the most pythonic way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the most pythonic way to do this ?

It depends by definion. If it is more preferable, most common and fastest way then `np.where` solution is here most pythonic way.

---

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), if need pandaic also this solutions are vectorized, so should be more preferable like [`apply` (loops under the hood)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/2901002):

```
df['final_target'] = np.where(df['city'].eq('paris'), 
                              df['city'] + '_' + df['arr'].astype(str), 
                              df['city'])
```

Pandas alternatives:

```
df['final_target'] = df['city'].mask(df['city'].eq('paris'), 
                                     df['city'] + '_' + df['arr'].astype(str))
```

---

```
df['final_target'] = df['city'].where(df['city'].ne('paris'), 
                                      df['city'] + '_' + df['arr'].astype(str))
print (df)
     city  arr final_target
0   paris   11     paris_11
1   paris   12     paris_12
2  dallas   22       dallas
3   miami   15        miami
4   paris   16     paris_16
```

**Performance**:

```
#50k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)
    

In [157]: %%timeit
     ...: df['final_target'] = np.where(df['city'].eq('paris'), 
     ...:                               df['city'] + '_' + df['arr'].astype(str), 
     ...:                               df['city'])
     ...:                               
48.6 ms ± 444 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [158]: %%timeit
     ...: df['city'] + (df['city'] == 'paris')*('_' + df['arr'].astype(str))
     ...: 
     ...: 
49.2 ms ± 1.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [159]: %%timeit
     ...: df['final_target'] = df['city']
     ...: df.loc[df['city'] == 'paris', 'final_target'] +=  '_' + df['arr'].astype(str)
     ...: 
63.8 ms ± 764 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [160]: %%timeit
     ...: df['final_target'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.city + '_' + str(x.arr) if x.city == 'paris' else x.city, axis = 1)
     ...: 
     ...: 
1.33 s ± 119 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Can you see the speeds comparisons in my solutions?

Comment: Do you have explanation as to why third speed in my solution fails due to memory but others dont?

Comment: @eroot163pi - not idea, maybe problems with masks.

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner code does the trick:

```py
df['final_target'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.city + '_' + str(x.arr) if x.city == 'paris' else x.city, axis = 1)
```

Comment: This solution is not pythonic in my opinion, because exist vectorized faster alternatives - check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/2901002

Comment: Why is it not pythonic?

Comment: I think becaue loops unter the hood. I add link for more explanation why should be avoided this `method`

Comment: It says that ```apply``` consumes a lot of memory, since the function is "applied" row by row. It might be slower than the other functions, but I don't think that this makes it "not pythonic"...

Comment: ya, it depends what means more pythonic. If it is more preferable, most common and fastest way then this is not pythonic.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It all lies in what "pythonic" truly means. Maybe if the user was looking for a "fast" way, then an alternative way would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Try this neat and and short two lines with `loc`:

```
df['final_target'] = df['city']
df.loc[df['city'] == 'paris', 'final_target'] +=  '_' + df.loc[df['city'] == 'paris', 'arr'].astype(str)
```

This solution firstly assigns `df['city']` as the `final_target` column, then adds the `arr` column separated by underscore if the `city` column is `paris`.

IMO this is probably the most Pythonic and neat way here.

---

```
print(df)
```

---

```
     city  arr final_target
0   paris   11     paris_11
1   paris   12     paris_12
2  dallas   22       dallas
3   miami   15        miami
4   paris   16     paris_16
```

Comment: I think this one takes more memory, fails on large input

Comment: @eroot163pi How about yours, apply is super slow...

Comment: @eroot163pi Oh sorry, i thought you were ql.user2511...

Comment: I am nor sure why that happens :P

Comment: df.loc and df.arr they dont have same shape but still your output is correct maybe it macthes the index. Still not clear about memory error and also the sampling. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314257/why-memory-error-when-using-loc-in-pandas-instead-of-direct-computing

Answer (score 0):

Pretty self explanatory, one line, looks pythonic

```py
df['city'] + (df['city'] == 'paris')*('_' + df['arr'].astype(str))
```

```
s = """city,arr,final_target
paris,11,paris_11
paris,12,paris_12
dallas,22,dallas
miami,15,miami
paris,16,paris_16"""
import pandas as pd
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s)).sample(1000000, replace=True)
df
```

Speeds

```py
%%timeit
df['city'] + (df['city'] == 'paris')*('_' + df['arr'].astype(str))
# 877 ms ± 19.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
%%timeit
df['final_target'] = np.where(df['city'].eq('paris'), 
                              df['city'] + '_' + df['arr'].astype(str), 
                              df['city'])
# 874 ms ± 19.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I am not sure why this example fails(update: failing due to sampling) but memory error is still a mystery [Why memory error when using .loc in pandas with sampling instead of direct computing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314257/why-memory-error-when-using-loc-in-pandas-with-sampling-instead-of-direct-compu)

```py
%%timeit
df['final_target'] = df['city']
df.loc[df['city'] == 'paris', 'final_target'] +=  '_' + df['arr'].astype(str)
```

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 892. GiB for an array with shape (119671145392,) and data type int64
```

Comment: what is number of rows for test speed?

Comment: I hope not 5 rows.

Comment: lol...sorry, lemme check on big ones

Comment: On big ones not much difference?

Comment: ya, it is same.

Comment: THird one is giving memory error